# How to display two tables from a Dataset in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a Dataset with 2 different tables. What I have to do is to display those tables in a DataGridView. What I have done with a reference is given below.

```
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "AutomateKDB"
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlCmd.Connection = Connection
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlDaK1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    sqlDaK1.Fill(Kds, "KA")

    sqlCmdeA.CommandText = "AutomateeAudIT_KAData"
    sqlCmdeA.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlCmdeA.Connection = Connection1
    sqlCmdeA.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlDaeK1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    sqlDaeK1.Fill(Kds, "eK")

    GridKnowledge.DataSource = Kds
```

But this is not working. Please help me with this.

Thanks In Advance.,

Comment: You have to add two GridView.

Comment: okay., So It is not possible to add two tables from a Dataset in a single DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that was posted to the msdn forums sometime ago.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0a63a483-5b15-40d6-afb4-8add6b4f244f

Alternatively, you might consider mixing winform and wpf, where I believe this is relatively easy...

Comment: The link was helpful.,Thank you..,

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different DataGridView or nest them. Take a look at MSDN article - [Nested Grids for Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164077.aspx) and Code Project article - [DataGridView with hierarchical data binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/hierarchgrid.aspx)

Comment: The Nested Grids comes under the Web Application. How can I use that in my Windows Application or is there any other ways to access that in my Windows Application?

Answer (score 1):

You make view of two tables .

1. open Server Explore
2. Click View
3. Adding Table
4. Select Field

Note same field in tables, select one of them

Comment: tried to fix your spelling: English rarely starts words with uppercase letters (it's not all a header, is it :-), please check if I didn't overdo it